# How to change upload destination from public to private when there are uploaded files in database?

Tags: 8, files

There are a few fields that uses public upload destination. I changed it globally right now, as far as I know it uses private upload destination from now.
But how can I change previously uploaded files' upload destination (programmatically)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dest = 'private://';
$file = file_move($file, $dest)
```

[Change individual file from public to private and vice-versa](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98560/change-individual-file-from-public-to-private-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Hey Jimmy, thanks for your contribution. Could you maybe add some more explanation. As link-only or code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: The linked answer is for D7. OP asks for D8.